# How to fix sudden Run-Time error '1004' on vba find function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, find, match

On part of code where I need to find in which row certain String appears code breaks throwing '1004' error. This started suddenly and originally code worked without issue. 
Option explicit is on and all variables defined! zRow returns last row as it should, xSelectC is really string that needs to be searched in range.

I've tried approach with application.match - same error appears, 
also, I've tried replacing with Range objects (Dim objRng as Range, Set objRng = ws3.Cells(1, "B")) but with no luck.

On the end, I've used For loop approach and it worked but as this is just part of much larger code and there is quite a number of parts that use this same approach I would like to avoid for loop and actually in general understand why suddenly this '1004' started to appear.

```
vRow = ws3.Range("B1:B" & zRow + 1).Find(What:=xSelectC, After:=ws3.Cells(1, "B"), SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
```

Instead of (for example) returning number of row 1244, it is throwing '1004'.

Comment: You're using `.Row` on a range that quite possibly does not exist. Imagine if `Find` does not return anything, how can you get the row number of a range that does not exist?

Comment: But Range does exist and have data in it. That's a thing. This code worked previously and somewhere during the testing after adding some other functionalities it started to throwing this error! I've checked... For example calling ws3.Cells(1, "B") returns "College" as it is really in the Sheet. ws3 is Sheet("raw") and 2871 is last row as zRow returns...

Comment: Why try and put everything in one line? In any case I think we need more than a single line of code.

Comment: As general rule you should explicitly define all relevant parameters of Find method - if you don't, they may change between executions.

Comment: I solved this by making a for loop but really don't understand why started to throwing a error when it worked previously and I haven't changed anything with that part of project!

Comment: @BrakNicku, I did defined in one of my attempts strictly every parameter of Find method (range objects, string...)

Comment: @Tim Stack. As said. Range exist!

Comment: You can tag me but I can't provide an answer with the current information provided

Answer (score 0):

The general approach you should take is to return the Find into a Range variable, test that variable for Not Nothing, and only then refer to its properties.

Something  like

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim research as Range, rAfter As Range

' ...
Set rSearch = ws3.Range("B1:B" & zRow + 1)
Set rAfter=ws3.Cells(1, "B")
Set rng = rSearch.Find(What:=xSelectC, After:=rAfter, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If rng is Nothing Then
   ' nothing found, what now?
Else
   vRow = rng.Row
   ' rest of your code
End If
```

Note that you should explicitly set parameters LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchBy, as they are saved each time Find is called _ either by code or the user.  Failure to set them can result in unexpected behaviour  [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: Hm... point is, when I go and search it manually in sheet (or use for loop to achieve same thing, or count it with Countif), string is found in row 1244, but when I try to use application.match or Find method it isn't found. I would just like to understand...And @Chrisneilsen, exception is already solved as code is not executing if string don't exist in range

Comment: Other things to check: is ws3 set? Is zRow >= 0 and < ~1000000?

Comment: Also add `Debug.Print ws3.Range("B1244").Value = xselectC` to confirm the values are the same or only look similar (extra spaces/invisible chars).

Comment: @ivan did you check the other things I mentioned?

Comment: ws3 is set to sheet("raw"). zRow is 2871

Comment: @BrakNicku it is returning True. I've checked this as I had similar issue back in some javascript code...

Comment: @Chrisneilsen, yes I've checked. I must say I'm a bit confused on this.

Comment: @ivan break it down a bit.  See my edit.  If it still errors, on which line?

Comment: On Set rng = rSearch.Find(What:=xSelectC, After:=rAfter, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

Comment: Hmmm... curious.  What's the value of xSelectC?  Failing that, would you be able to up load a copy of the workbook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197493/discussion-between-ivan-kocis-and-chris-neilsen).

Comment: @Ivan - I had a look at your file.  I don't have a full answer, but did notice something.  When you click `Business (UNDERGRADUATE)` an event `lboxCollegeList_Click()` fires that runs the code in question `loadSelectedCollegeDepartments`, successfully.  It then runs `lboxDeptList.RowSource = "DepartmentList"`  When you click `LOAD FACULTY LIST` another event fires that runs code that includes `ws4.Range("W2:Y" & xRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, header:=xlNo`.   ...

Comment: (Continued) This modifies the range that you have set  `lboxDeptList.RowSource` to, which fires the change event, which calls `loadSelectedCollegeDepartments` again, which fails this time.  I can't explain why it fails in this circumstance, but it seems to be tied up with the `RemoveDuplicates` call.  You could try setting `lboxDeptList.RowSource` to nothing while the code runs, then resetting it after.

Comment: Also I see you have a few Named Ranges with Ref errors.  These may of may not be a factor

Comment: Ref named ranges are declared later. Shouldn't affect code in this part of process. I've tried to trace events too and came to same conclusion. Ill try what you've suggested!